# Polynomial $ax^2+bx^4+cx^6+dx^8$.

Tags: calculus, analysis, mathematical-physics

The[image] the plot of polynomial $-7.7x^2+4.30x^4-0.802x^6+0.0476x^8$, in which two sides wells are shrinked according to middle wells. Can any body guide me which changes in coefficients can be made so that i can get four well of equi-distance and same depth.?

Comment: You can get either equidistant wells, say by integrating $(x+3)(x+2)(x+1)x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$, but then they won’t be of same height.

Comment: Not entirely clear on what you are after, but maybe look at the [Chebyshev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#First_kind)-inspired  [$128 x^8 - 256 x^6 + 160 x^4 -32 x^2$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=128+x%5E8+-+256+x%5E6+%2B+160+x%5E4+-32+x%5E2) then rescale the x-axis as needed

Comment: Will $$\sum_{n=0}^{17}\frac{\left(-1\right)^nx^{2n}}{\left(2n\right)!}$$ work ?  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6dpvjxpgdf

Comment: Chebyshev (see dxiv's comment) gives local maxima/minima all at the same heights but varying distances. $(x^2-3^2)^2(x^2-1^2)^2$ gives equidistant minima all at the same depth, but the maxima vary. I doubt you can get all the properties you might want with a degree 8 polynomial. Which property are you willing to relax?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen There is no place for doubt. Your polynomial is _the only one_ with four equidistant minima at the same depth (up to scaling and translation).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen but degree of the polynomial should not be incresed from power 8; actually there are few other limitations like depth and width of the wells should be same. As in quantum mechanics these polynomials corresponds to dfferent cases of anharmonic oscillators with multiple wells; if these conditions hold then there may be some interseting behaviours can be seen; so why i am interested in it to pick this specific case; when there is a 4 fourl $x^8$ polynomial where each well is uniform in its depth and width.

Comment: Mike, read what I suspected and Ivan Neretin confirmed: *That cannot be done with a degree 8 polynomial.* Either the depths of the well, the width of the wells, or the degree of the polynomial has to change. You need to compromise one of the requirements. By the way, do you measure the width of your well as a distance between the bottoms, the distance between the tops, or at some height in-between.

Comment: Each well is of unit length and width. So in this way the barrier heigh between two connected well is also unit length.

Comment: @Mike It sounds like you still didn't get it. There is no solution. Why do you hink there should be?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen, yes i got the point. It looks impossible to get uniform four wells from polynomial of 8th-degree. Thanks for your's concenterations.